# displaying page at client side (getting data from lua using socket.request)

Tags: extjs, lua

i am trying to reach a cross domain server using lua.
i get a response from the server (the html code).
now, i need this page that i got to display at my site.

Code:

```
    --body, header, status, error

b, h, s, e = socket.http.request{url = "http://someurl"
    , proxy = "http://someProxy"
    , sink = ltn12.sink.file(io.stdout)

    }
```

the sink attribute does his job and prints the html back to the client side.
on the client side i am developing with extjs.
my question, is how do i display the page that was recieved ?

Thx,
Yoni

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to capture the output into a string in Lua, rather than having the sink be `io.stdout`, then use that string with one of the "[3 ways to render HTML inside of a ExtJS container](http://www.marcusschiesser.de/?p=113)".

As for writing the data to a string instead of stdout, that might look like this:

```
local t = {}
sink = ltn12.sink.table(t)
-- ...
local html = table.concat(t)
```